# User defined scalar-valued functions in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Say I have defined an SQL Server function say `myfunc` which takes a integer as input and returns an integer like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc
(@val as INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        @val + 10
END
```

**Is there a way to call this function in SQLAlchemy?** I know I can't do as below, as it is not a recognized built-in function name (`'myfunc' is not a recognized built-in function name.`)

```
select(func.myfunc(x.c.mycolumn).label("my_column_plus_10"))
```

Comment: Why not call it using raw sql in sqlalchemy? [Additional reference for potential answer](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scalar-valued UDFs must be called using schema-qualified name in SQL Server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc
(@val as INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        @val + 10
END
go
select myfunc(1) --fails
go
select dbo.myfunc(1) --succeeds
```

So try:

```
select(func.dbo.myfunc(x.c.mycolumn).label("my_column_plus_10"))
```

per:

> To call functions which are present in dot-separated packages, specify
> them in the same manner:
>
> `>>> print(func.stats.yield_curve(5, 10))`
>
> `stats.yield_curve(:yield_curve_1, :yield_curve_2)`

[sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=func#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func)

Here it's a schema-qualified UDF not a "dot-separated package", but the generated SQL looks the same.